# Multiple instances of pygame.event.get()

Tags: python, events, pygame

There are two `for event in pygame.event.get():` instances. It doesn't work inside the second one. I guess that calling the function twice will not work. What should be done here? By the way this is a function to move a piece from square to square in a board game.

```
def movement_one(blit1,charac1,screen,squareblitter,boardcoord,placecheck_True):
    global mouse1, mouse1_des
    run1=True
    while run1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse1 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                for i in range(80):
                    if squareblitter[i].collidepoint(mouse1):
                        collided = i
                        break
                print "wow"
                print i
                print collided in placecheck_True
                if collided in placecheck_True:
                    #checks if the square is occupied or not
                    print "wiw"
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        print "wtf"
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            exit()
                        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                            mouse1_des = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                            print "omg"
                            squareblitter[i]
                            pygame.display.update()
                            for i in range(80):
                                if squareblitter[i].collidepoint(mouse1_des):
                                    screen.blit(placecheck_True[collided], squareblitter[i])
                                    placecheck_True.update[i]=placecheck_True[collided]
                                    pygame.display.update()
                                    run1=False
                                    break
                else:
                    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `pygame.event.get()` again while handling an event from a previous call usually won't work. It's unclear from your code precisely what you're trying to accomplish. However, I suggest you rry moving the code for processing `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` events when there's a collision that's currently in you inner `for event` loop to the outer one (and remove the inner `for event` loop altogether).

Here's what I mean (untested, of course):

```
def movement_one(blit1, charac1, screen, squareblitter, boardcoord, placecheck_True):
    global mouse1, mouse1_des
    run1 = True
    while run1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse1 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                for i in range(80):
                    if squareblitter[i].collidepoint(mouse1):
                        collided = i
                        break
                print "wow"
                print i
                print collided in placecheck_True
                if collided in placecheck_True:
                    mouse1_des = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    print "omg"
                    squareblitter[i]
                    pygame.display.update()
                    for i in range(80):
                        if squareblitter[i].collidepoint(mouse1_des):
                            screen.blit(placecheck_True[collided], squareblitter[i])
                            placecheck_True.update[i] = placecheck_True[collided]
                            pygame.display.update()
                            run1 = False  # not sure you should do this...
                            break
```